# Can I follow and make the similar to a state document that is open to the public

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, public-domain

I am trying to make an Request for Proposal (RFP) and I found a similar one made by the state of NM. The RFP is open to the public; other parts are not as they are confidential. Can I make a similar one and used it because I liked the way they made theirs and liked some words they put in the RFP.

Comment: I know that works by the US *federal* government [are often exempt from copyright](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/105). But I would also be curious if works on state level have similar copyright exemptions.

Comment: @Philipp They do not. Edicts of government aren't copyrightable; however, anything else is at the state level.

Comment: I am talking about this specific doc. http://www.dps.state.nm.us/docs/RFP/14-790-0020-RFP-Aircraft-Broker-and-Appraisal-Services.pdf